# How to link custom C (which itself needs special linking options to compile) with Cython?

Tags: c, linker, cython, distutils

so I'm trying to create a Cython module which uses a .c file that I've written. That .c file needs a special linking option (to compile it, I need `gcc -o mycode mycode.c -lfftw3f`). I could potentially just rewrite my .c file in Cython, but I want to know how to do this.

I am using fftw3, and when compiling, you need to use the `-lfftw3f` option IN ADDITION to `#include <fftw3.h>` in the .c file if you want to use the float version, which I do.

My `setup.py` looks like the following:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

sourcefiles = ['mycode_caller.pyx', 'mycode.c']

ext_modules = [Extension("myext", sourcefiles, libraries=['fttw3f'])]

setup(
  name = 'My Extension',
  cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
  ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

I made a header file called `mycode.h` which looks like the following, and includes a prototype for the `transform()` function, which is defined in `mycode.c`:

```
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <math.h>

#ifndef FOURIER_H_INCLUDED
#define FOURIER_H_INCLUDED
fftwf_complex** transform(float** in, int length);
#endif
```

And my Cython file, `mycode_caller.pyx` looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cdef extern from "stdlib.h":
    void free(void* ptr)
    void* malloc(size_t size)

cdef extern from "fftw3.h":
    struct fftwf_complex:
        pass

cdef extern from "fourier.h":
    fftwf_complex** transform(float** in_arr, int length)

cdef float** npy2c_float2d(np.ndarray[float, ndim=2] a):
    cdef float** a_c = <float**>malloc(a.shape[0] * sizeof(float*))
    for k in range(a.shape[0]):
        a_c[k] = &a[k, 0]
    return a_c

cpdef test_transform(data):
    nparr = np.zeros([14, 31])
    c_array = npy2c_float2d(nparr)
    ans = transform(c_array, 31)
```

When I run `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`, it builds fine, but if I try to import it, it will claim the following:

`ImportError: ./myext.so: undefined symbol: fftwf_execute`

This error happens as a result of not having the `-lfftw3f` option passed to gcc during compilation. How do I resolve this? There's no way to specify linker commands in a .c source file right? Do I need to tell Cython.Distutils to use this option somehow?
Thank you for your help!

EDIT:
So, I added `libraries=[fttw3f]` to my `setup.py` file, and now it throws an error on build:

```
gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/emodsp.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/fourier.o -lfftw3f -o /home/carson/Documents/Caltech/Senior/Winter/art89/Project/openepoc/emodsp.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libfftw3f.a(alloc.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libfftw3f.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `libraries` option to `Extension`:

```
Extension("myext", sourcefiles, libraries = ['fftw3f'], library_dirs = ['/path/to/fftw/libs'])
```

Comment: This is helpful, thank you! But now it throws a different error.

Comment: Do you have the shared-library version of `fftw3f`, or only the static version? Linking a static library into a shared library sometimes results in issues like this.

Comment: @nneonneo If downloading a shared library is not an option, how can the issue of linking a static library to a shared library be fixed?