# Compiling Cython with C header files error

Tags: c++, c, linker, cython, distutils

So I'm trying to wrap some C code with Cython. I read read applied Cython's tutorials on doing this ([1](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/clibraries.html), [2](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html)), but these tutorials do not say much on how to compile the code once you have wrapped it with Cython, and so I have an error saying it can't find my C code.

First, my cython script ("calcRMSD.pyx"):

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cdef extern from "rsmd.h":
    double rmsd(int n, double* x, double* y)

#rest of the code ommited
```

The C code I am trying to wrap ("rmsd.h"):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

extern "C" {
  // svd from lapack
  void dgesvd_(char*,char*,int*,int*,double*,int*,double*,double*,int*,double*,
           int*,double*,int*,int*);
}

double rmsd(int n, double* x, double* y)
{
   //code omitted
}
```

Setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy as np


setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize([Extension("calcRMSD", 
                            sources = ["calcRMSD.pyx"],
                            include_dirs = [np.get_include()],
                            libraries = ["dgesvd"]
                            #extra_compile_args = ["-I."],
                            #extra_link_args = ["-L./usr/lib/liblapack.dylib"]
                            )])

)
```

My error:

```
calcRMSD.c:269:10: fatal error: 'rsmd.h' file not found
#include "rsmd.h"
```

I read this stack overflow thread
[Using Cython To Link Python To A Shared Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993927/using-cython-to-link-python-to-a-shared-library)

but following it gives me different errors. If I try to put rmsd.h in sources, it says it doesnt recognize the file type.

[How to link custom C (which itself needs special linking options to compile) with Cython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951798/how-to-link-custom-c-which-itself-needs-special-linking-options-to-compile-wit?rq=1)

This looks somewhat promising but im not sure how to use it.

Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all it has to find the include file, `rsmd.h`. You need to add the path where this header can be found to the `include_dirs` parameter. The error about the missing file should disappear.

Then you will additionally need to include the library you get from compiling that C code. If that's `librsmd.a` you would add `'rsmd'` to the `libraries` parameter. Additionally you might need a `library_dirs` parameter that contains the path where that library can be found.

Comment: rmsd.h is in the same directory as the rest of my files, so i set include_dirs to include_dirs = [np.get_include(), '.'], but I still get the missing file error

Comment: Does it work if you specify the complete path? The setup script might compile in a different directory, like a `build/` subdir, maybe that's a problem.

Comment: Changing it to a complete path worked! (I also had to fix a typo). I now have new errors in the compilation of rmsd.h, but I will try to figure those out. thank you!

Comment: @sth What should be done with the library file librsmd.a? If I follow what you suggested, it comes up with the error saying that -lrsmd is not a recognized library.

Comment: @paulinho: I assume that means it doesn't find the librsmd.a file. You could try to add a `library_dirs = ['/some/dir']` parameter that contains the directory where the `.a` file is.

Comment: @sth But you would keep the statement libraries = ['rsmd']? What purpose does that serve then?

Comment: @paulinho `libraries` says what libraries to use, `library_dirs` says in which directories to search for them.